# Minecraft / Ubuntu blank screen

Tags: drivers, lubuntu, java, minecraft

I am pretty new to Linux world.
I try to get Minecraft working on my son's PC.
I have Lubuntu 16.04 and when I start Minecraft (11.1.2), all I got is a blank screen. I can hear the sound/music but that's it.

I have read many forums/discussions on the subject and tried various things since one month.

- I have uninstall the open java version, I had installed previously, because I read this might be the source of the problem.
- I have install the Oracle/Sun java version 6 instead, but screen remains blank.
- I have also tried with Oracle/Sun Java 7. Same thing.
- I have completely removed Minecraft (also the `~/.Minecraft` directory) and re-installed it (using `apt-get`).
- I have checked the graphic drivers: I have an old Dell d600 (thus Lubuntu), with an AMD Radeon graphic chip; drivers seem up to date.

I am running out of idea right now.
Any help on that will be more than welcomed.

Comment: Hi and welcome to AskUbuntu! Please [edit](https://askubuntu.com/posts/904719/edit) your question to include the output of `lspci`. Thanks!

Comment: A Dell Latitude D600 is pretty much obsolete by today's standards and way below the minimum system requirements for Minecraft - https://help.mojang.com/customer/en/portal/articles/325948-minecraft-system-requirements - so you should set your expectations accordingly. On top of that, even when new, it was underpowered for many games for the simple reason the Dell's Latitude line wasn't and still isn't designed for games but for professional (office and similar) use only.